# How to decode a video file straight to a Direct3D11 texture using Windows Media Foundation?

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation

I'd like to decode the contents of a video file to a Direct3D11 texture and  avoid the copies back and forth to CPU memory. Ideally, the library will play the audio itself and call back into my code whenever a video frame has been decoded.

On the surface, the Windows Media Foundation's IMFPMediaPlayer (ie MFPCreateMediaPlayer() and IMFPMediaPlayer::CreateMediaItemFromURL()) seem like a good match, except that the player decodes straight to the app's HWND. The documentation implies that I can add a custom video sink, but I have not been able to find documentation nor sample code on how to do that. Please point me in the right direction.

Currently, I am using libVLC to accomplish the above, but it only provides the video surface in CPU memory, which can become a bottleneck for my use-case.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I can recommend try CaptureManager SDK: [NativeMediaFoundationPlayer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK#fourtyfirstdemoprogram) - this demo program for DirectX9, but it can display into ID3D11Texture2D.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this source code from my project 'Stackoverflow' : [MFVideoEVR](https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow/tree/master/MFVideoEVR)

> This program shows how to setup EVR (enhanced video renderer), and how to provide video samples to it, using a Source Reader.

The key is to provide video samples, so you can use them for your purpose.

This program provides samples through IMFVideoSampleAllocator. It is for DirectX9 texture. You need to change source code, and to use IMFVideoSampleAllocatorEx, instead : [IMFVideoSampleAllocatorEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nn-mfidl-imfvideosampleallocatorex)

About MFCreateVideoSampleAllocatorEx :

> This function creates an allocator for DXGI video surfaces. The buffers created by this allocator expose the IMFDXGIBuffer interface.

So to retreive texture : [IMFDXGIBuffer::GetResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/mfobjects/nf-mfobjects-imfdxgibuffer-getresource)

> You can use this method to get a pointer to the ID3D11Texture2D interface of the surface. If the buffer is locked, the method returns MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST.

You will also have to manage sound through IMFSourceReader.

With this approach, there is no copy back to system memory.

PS : You don't talk about video format (h265, h264, mpeg2, others ??). MediaFoundation doesn't handle all video format, natively.

Comment: Thanks, your sample code works! (without audio). I modified it to use DXGI, but unfortunately it turned out that MFCreateVideoSampleAllocatorEx is not available in Windows 7.